# Docker ENV LD_PRELOAD prevent container crash but throw java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ls": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, docker, quarkus, alpine-linux

I have a problem while call `com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getFirestore()` in a Java Application inside a Quarkus Server which is Running on an Alpine 3.15.4 inside a Docker container.

I have created a small demo. The results are:

**Configuration 1**
Enable in the docker file

```
RUN apk update
RUN apk --no-cache add curl ca-certificates openjdk11-jre-headless
```

Results:
init ok
shell fail

**Configuration2**
Disable in the docker file

```
#RUN apk update
#RUN apk --no-cache add curl ca-certificates openjdk11-jre-headless
```

Results:
init fail
shell ok

**If init fail this error is logged**

```
[de.ibe.DemoResource] (executor-thread-0) getFirestore
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000003efe, pid=1, tid=142
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.15+10) (build 11.0.15+10-alpine-r0)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.15+10-alpine-r0, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000003efe
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /deployments/hs_err_pid1.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/issues
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

**If shell fail this error is logged**

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ls": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
        at de.ibe.DemoResource.shell(DemoResource.java:72)
        at de.ibe.DemoResource.demo(DemoResource.java:37)
```

If found some bug reports e.g.

```
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/8751 (see varpa89 commented on 28 Apr)  
https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/2776
```

One workaround would be to create two container with different docker files. But I would prefer one container..

Hope someone can held me!

Here is the code of the demo

```
package de.ibe;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.jaxrs.PathParam;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient;

@Path("/demo")
public class DemoResource {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DemoResource.class);

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/{command}")
    public String demo(@PathParam String command) {

        try {
            if (command == null || command.equals("")) {
                return "command null or empty";
            } else if (command.equals("init")) {
                LOG.info("run init");
                return this.init();
            } else if (command.equals("shell")) {
                LOG.info("run shell");
                return this.shell();
            } else {
                return "unkown command";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e);
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    private String init() throws IOException {
        try (InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/demo-b9aa8a6.json")) {
            if (in == null) {
                return "init in is null";
            }

            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(in);

            LOG.info("options");
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(credentials).build();

            LOG.info("initializeApp");
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

            LOG.info("getFirestore");
            FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

        }

        return "init ok";
    }

    private String shell() {
        try {
            final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("ls");
            builder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "shell error";
        }

        return "shell ok";
    }

}
```

Docker file

```
FROM alpine:3.15.4

ARG RUN_JAVA_VERSION=1.3.8
ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en'

# Install java and the run-java script
RUN apk update
RUN apk --no-cache add curl ca-certificates openjdk11-jre-headless

# init ok but shell false, enable
#RUN apk add gcompat
#ENV LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libgcompat.so.0

RUN mkdir /deployments
RUN chmod "g+rwX" /deployments
RUN curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric8/run-java-sh/${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}/run-java-sh-${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}-sh.sh -o /deployments/run-java.sh
RUN chmod 540 /deployments/run-java.sh

# Configure the JAVA_OPTIONS, you can add -XshowSettings:vm to also display the heap size.
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"

# We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
COPY target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "/deployments/run-java.sh" ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to solve the problem so I found a second "workaround".
Workarounds
1.Use 2 containers with different configuration.2
2.Use an other OS than alpin.

I used debian instead of alpin and the problem disappear.

```
FROM debian:11.3

ARG RUN_JAVA_VERSION=1.3.8
ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en'


#debian special--------------------------------------------
#install curl -y=send yes to input
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install curl -y


#install jdk
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 /usr/share/man/man2
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-11-jre
#----------------------------------------------------------

RUN mkdir /deployments
RUN chmod "g+rwX" /deployments
RUN curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric8/run-java-sh/${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}/run-java-sh-${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}-sh.sh -o /deployments/run-java.sh
RUN chmod 540 /deployments/run-java.sh


# Configure the JAVA_OPTIONS, you can add -XshowSettings:vm to also display the heap size.
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"


# We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
COPY target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/


EXPOSE 8080 
ENTRYPOINT [ "/deployments/run-java.sh" ]
```